# Receiving error "net::ERR_H2_OR_QUIC_REQUIRED" when using fetch api with a stream as its body

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I am trying to send an HTTP request using fetch with a stream as its body ([reference](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/fetch-streaming-requests/)). The request is being sent to my node server. However, I am getting the error "net::ERR_H2_OR_QUIC_REQUIRED" on the client side.

In the request body, I am simply writing numbers from 0 to 4 after a 2 seconds interval. This is the code for sending the request:

```
const encoder = new TextEncoder();

const stream = new ReadableStream({
    start: (controller) => {
        let i = 0;
        const id = setInterval(() => {
            controller.enqueue(encoder.encode(`${i}`));
            if(++i === 5){
                clearInterval(id);
                controller.close();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
});

await fetch('/stream', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: stream,
    duplex: 'half',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    }
});
```

This is how the error looks in the console:
[image]

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: The document you linked has the answer: the Streams API [doesn't work over HTTP 1(.1)](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/fetch-streaming-requests/#doesnt-work-on-http1x). I don't have time to write a full answer why that is & showing you how to set-up a HTTP2 or HTTP3 server, but if you figure that out by yourself, you can post and accept your own answer to this question (to help others in the future).

Comment: I get it that it doesn't work over http/1.1 but I don't understand the reason. According to [the article](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/fetch-streaming-requests/#doesnt-work-on-http1x), HTTP/1.1 rules requires that request and response bodies either need to send a Content-Length header, so the other side knows how much data it'll receive, or change the format of the message to use chunked encoding. So shouldn't adding the header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" resolve this issue? @RickN please answer if you have time. Thank you.

Comment: as far as i known, a lot of backend servers don't support receving streaming request, as such browsers aren't implementing it. chrome 105 allowing to streaming request but only making it work on quic.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the error `ERR_H2_OR_QUIC_REQUIRED` meant that the server I was sending the request to didn't have http2 enabled.

Enabling http2 on the server (for me was Nginx) - solved the issue:

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl http2;
   server_name example.com;
   ...
}
```

Streaming also requires a browser version that provides support - [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream).